# writing logic Date difference - Newbie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to subtract the current date by `5`. say if today is `2008-12-9` i need to get  the date 5 days back. If we output this, the date should display as `2008-12-4`.

How can i code this programatically? or a tutorial that would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/)

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[offsetComponents setDays:-5];

NSDate *fiveDaysAgo = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
```

to convert it to a string with the preferred format, use [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fiveDaysAgo];
```

Comment: Certain months have 30 or 31 days, say if today is `October 1st`, will the code know that `September` has only `30 days` , and print the result as `25th Septemeber` ?

Comment: Should the `date` part from the line `NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];` be `fiveDaysAgo` from `NSDate *fiveDaysAgo =  ...` ? Sorry i am a beginner

Answer (score 3):

Always use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents for date calculations. This will take into account oddities like leap years with 29 days in February, leap seconds and daylight saving changes.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; // Using current date here
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

components.day = - 5; // Find date for 5 days ago

NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the brute-force way:

1. Sustract `5` from `DAY`.
2. If `DAY < 0`, add number of days of the previous month and sustract `1` from `MONTH`.
3. If `MONTH < 0`, add number of month of a year and sustract `1` from `YEAR`.

The advantage of the brute-force approach is that it will work with every language.

Comment: If you want to do this correctly then you will need to take into account leap years and other calendar changed. Just use NSCalendar.

Comment: @Robin Summerhill: Downvote means that the answer is not useful. Are you suggesting that my method wouldn't work?

Comment: I'm suggesting that as it stands it is not accurate because it doesn't take into account calendar changes. To do it properly you would basically be duplicating what NSCalendar does already - so use NSCalendar. There are two other answers to this question that offer better advice.

Comment: It's nothing personal. It's just that if someone searches for this question in the future, the answers that offer the correct way of doing it should be at the top of the list.

Comment: I'm not taking it personal, I just disagree. I understand why you wouldn't upvote it, but I don't why you would downvote it. I see three answers using practically the same idea and one different (mine). There's already an accepted answer that will be at the top. And I'm not saying mine is better, faster or shorter than the other three, but it **is** correct, it is didactic and it can be easily implemented in **every** programming language.

Comment: I don't want to labour this point but: first of all your method requires the day, month and year components to be extracted from the supplied date. This will be dependent on things like the current locale and calendar in use. Then you will need to know all about calendar oddities like leap days. Not all users will be using the Gregorian calendar - some calendars don't have a 'February' let alone a February whose number of days changes. So yes, you could implement your method in **every** programming language and it would be **inaccurate** in every programming language.

Comment: By the way - there are two answers using the correct approach (NSCalendar) and two that don't. My downvote of your answer was to give the two correct answers 1 vote and the two incorrect answers 0 votes. That is why I didn't downvote the other incorrect answer to give it -1 vote.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define SOME_HOUR -24*5

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDate *someDay = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*SOME_HOUR sinceDate:today];
```

Comment: due to DST days might be 23, 24 or 25 hours long.